# Adding active class to menu item on section scroll

Tags: jquery, html

I have this following code. It works but only problem is its not adding active class to menu li a item as it scrolls to the section.
Please help

```
<nav class="nav-1">
    <ul class="menu nav_menu_css_class">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#section1-1" class="menu_item active-right"></a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#section1-2" class="menu_item"></a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#section1-3" class="menu_item"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>   
<div class="center_pages_wrap" id="center_pages_wrap">
    <section id="section1-1" class="current-section" name="section1-1"></section>
    <section id="section1-2" name="section1-2"></section>
    <section id="section1-3" name="section1-3"></section>
</div>    
<script>
    var sections = jQuery('.sections1');
    var nav = jQuery('.right_menu_wrap nav.nav-1');
    var nav_height = nav.outerHeight()+130;         
    jQuery(window).on('scroll', function () {
      var cur_pos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();         
      sections.each(function() {
        var top = jQuery(this).offset().top - nav_height,
          bottom = top + jQuery(this).outerHeight();         
        if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
          nav.find('a').removeClass('active-right');
          sections.removeClass('current-section');
          jQuery(this).addClass('current-section');
          nav.find('a[href="#'+jQuery(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active-right');
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please give your CSS code as well

Comment: Try removing the word 'content' from the section ids. Right now 'a[href="#'+jQuery(this).attr('id')+'"]' would equal #content section1-3, which correlates with nothing.

Comment: Yes. that was it thank you oMiKey.